# Get n-th minimum of vector elements

Tags: c++

I have a std vector where each element describes a point in 3D space. Thus every point has X, Y and Z coordinate. The task now is to loop over all points and find not the point that has the smallest distance to the reference point but e.g. the second or third smallest distance. This distance is then returned

My problem is the felxible implementation to find the n-th smallest distance.
Below code is for 1D space where every point has the same position to simplify the example.

```
std::vector<double> point(10, 1.0);
double min_distance = 0.0;

for (int i = 0; i < point.size(); ++i)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < point.size(); ++j)
  {
    if (i == j)
      continue;

    min_distance = std::min(min_distance, std::abs(point[j] - point[i]));
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd venture to say you're looking for `std::nth_element`.

Comment: I think you could adapt the [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm to solve your problem. It has the nice property that you can find the n-th smallest element in O(n) time.

Comment: @vydesaster If two elements of the vector that has only two elements have the same value then what is the second smallest element?

Comment: There is no "reference point" in your 1D implementation.

Comment: quickselect can be the right algorithm in general but my guess this question needs a pretty basic answer for a beginner; OP can correct me if I'm wrong.  (BTW in C++ quickselect is spelled `std::nth_element` as cigien above remarks) (but in this case it might be "expensive" if you consider the cost of computing euclidean distance expensive)

Comment: @HTNW - no, but used naively it would calculate euclidean distances from the reference point repeatedly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`std::nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) function which will do a partial sort of your array based on your predicate:

```cpp
std::vector<double> points;
std::nth_element(points.begin(), points.begin() + n, points.end());
```

where `n` is your nth element. If you want to get all the elements that are inferior just `std::sort` your array and take the right one.

The advantage of `std::nth_element` is that it may be linear in the number of elements whereas `std::sort` is in `O(nlogn)` in worst case.

Note that if you use `std::nth_element`, your array won't be sorted, but you are only guaranteed instead that your nth element is in position `n`.

EDIT: updated example with custom distance

```cpp
Point reference;
std::vector<Point> points;
std::nth_element(points.begin(), points.begin() + n, points.end(),
    [&reference](const Point& a, const Point& b) { return dist(reference, a) < dist(reference, b); });
```

or you can wrap you comparator inside a struct:

```cpp
struct PointComp
{
  Point reference;
  bool operator<(const Point& a, const Point& b)
  {
    return dist(reference, a) < dist(reference, b);
  }

};

PointComp comp; comp.reference = reference;
std::vector<Point> points;
std::nth_element(points.begin(), points.begin() + n, points.end(), comp);
```

if you don't like lambda for some reason.

Comment: but where's your distance computation? and how much does it cost to use it as part of the comparator?

Comment: You can pass your distance computation in the nth_element function either by using a lambda or wrapping it inside a struct.

As for the cost, the documentation says `O(N) applications of the predicate, and O(N log N) swaps, where N = last - first.`

Comment: yeah i know. and now that you've updated your answer - everyone will know, thanks!

Comment: @ThomasCaissard Thanks for the quick answer. I think this the solution I have looked for. As long as the n-th element is at position n everything is fine for me.

Comment: @vydesaster you're welcomed! Yeah this is the purpose of `nth_element` :)

Comment: `std::nth_element(std::execution::par, ...` could be worth trying.

Comment: I'd be cautious with the use of `std::execution::par` especially if you are sorting a low number of points (< 10k). In any case you should benchmark it to see what's better for you!

Comment: @ThomasCaissard Indeed - and different implementations are ... different. I've had very good results doing similar calculations with quite small sets in one implementation but not as good in another (and I think both uses tbb so it's a bit odd). Measuring is key.

Comment: Yeah it also vastly depends on the compiler you are using, which also means the platform!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a function that computes the distance between 2 `Point`s.

```
auto distance = [](Point a, Point b) { return ... };
```

and a reference point `Point ref;`, you can find the [nth-element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) like this:

```
std::nth_element(points.begin(), points.begin() + n, points.end(), 
                 [&](Point a, Point b) { 
                      return distance(a, ref) < distance(b, ref); 
                 });
```

and now the nth-element of `points` is what you're looking for.

Note that the distance to the reference point is computed more often than strictly necessary, so you might want to precompute that instead.